# Many to One relation - join with only one value - Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have following situation. There's some event with multiple periods when it's active.

```
| Event |
---------
| id    |
| name  |
| owner |


| Runtime |
-----------
| id      |
| idEvent |
| start   |
| end     |
```

Now, I want to get a list of all events owned by specific users with the earliest start date and latest end date. For instance for following rows:

```
event
id = 2, name = "foo", owner = 1

runtime
id = 1, idEvent = 2, start = "2015-08-10", end = "2015-08-15"
id = 2, idEvent = 2, start = "2015-08-20", end = "2015-08-25"
```

I'd like to get result

```
event.id = 2, name = "foo", owner = 1, minstart = "2015-08-10", maxend = "2015-08-25"
```

How can I achieve this using Doctrine 2? Of course there can be more fields in the final result but these are crucial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution - kind of trivial in fact but it might help someone:

```
//$qb is an instance of QueryBuilder
$qb->select('e.id, e.name, min(r.dateStart) AS min_start, max(r.dateEnd) as max_end')
    ->from('Entity\Event', 'e')
    ->leftJoin('e.eventRuntimes', 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case I would add methods minstart and maxend in event model and calculate the value in php not using database or doctrine. 
It should be a simple script, you run throw runtime ArrayCollection and try to find min value of start or max value of end.

One more thing I think that is One to Many relationship not Many to one and probably Unidirectional.